# Find out what is hidden!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

> **Ca*n* y*o*u find what is hidden wi*t*hin t*h*is puzzl*e*? Only the best puzzle*r* can get the corr*e*ct answer!**

[image]
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

> Easter

Because

> When clicking edit, two things are noticed. First is that the italics say 'Not here', and the second is that there are far more imgur picture links than there are pictures shown.
>
>  [One of those images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TaHe.png) is a picture of a cross, and as it was easter yesterday that is the answer

Comment: Good Job you got it :D